# Jenkins-Job fails

Tags: php, jenkins

I have setup an uberSVN Server with Jenkins running to control an SVN-Repository with PHP-WebWare.

I've been encountering problems and looking for solutions to them for many hours. Now I hope that this is the last one, but I don't find any answers:

```
Publishing Clover coverage report...
Publishing Clover HTML report...
Publishing Clover XML report...
Publishing Clover coverage results...
[htmlpublisher] Archiving HTML reports...
[htmlpublisher] Archiving at BUILD level /opt/ubersvn/jenkins/workspace/JenkinsTest/build/api to /opt/ubersvn/jenkins/jobs/JenkinsTest/builds/2013-03-12_12-56-15/htmlreports/API_Documentation
ERROR: Directory '/opt/ubersvn/jenkins/workspace/JenkinsTest/build/api' exists but failed copying to '/opt/ubersvn/jenkins/jobs/JenkinsTest/builds/2013-03-12_12-56-15/htmlreports/API_Documentation'.
ERROR: This is especially strange since your build otherwise succeeded.
Build step 'Publish HTML reports' changed build result to FAILURE
```

Here the Jenkins.log

```
12.03.2013 12:56:17 hudson.model.Run run
INFO: JenkinsTest #37 main build action completed: SUCCESS
```

Can anyone tell me what the problem here is?

EDIT:
Here -for better analysis- the complete log

```
Building in workspace /opt/ubersvn/jenkins/workspace/JenkinsTest
Cleaning up /opt/ubersvn/jenkins/workspace/JenkinsTest/.
Deleting /opt/ubersvn/jenkins/workspace/JenkinsTest/./cache.properties
Deleting /opt/ubersvn/jenkins/workspace/JenkinsTest/./build/API_Documentation
Deleting /opt/ubersvn/jenkins/workspace/JenkinsTest/./build/api
Deleting /opt/ubersvn/jenkins/workspace/JenkinsTest/./build/code-browser
Deleting /opt/ubersvn/jenkins/workspace/JenkinsTest/./build/coverage
Deleting /opt/ubersvn/jenkins/workspace/JenkinsTest/./build/logs
Deleting /opt/ubersvn/jenkins/workspace/JenkinsTest/./build/pdepend
Deleting /opt/ubersvn/jenkins/workspace/JenkinsTest/./build/phpdox
Updating http://svn.xyz.de:80/JenkinsTest/trunk
At revision 25
no change for http://svn.xyz.de:80/JenkinsTest/trunk since the previous build
[JenkinsTest] $ ant
Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in /opt/ubersvn/jre1.6.0_24-64/lib/tools.jar
Buildfile: /opt/ubersvn/jenkins/workspace/JenkinsTest/build.xml

clean:

prepare:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /opt/ubersvn/jenkins/workspace/JenkinsTest/build/api
    [mkdir] Created dir: /opt/ubersvn/jenkins/workspace/JenkinsTest/build/API_Documentation
    [mkdir] Created dir: /opt/ubersvn/jenkins/workspace/JenkinsTest/build/code-browser
    [mkdir] Created dir: /opt/ubersvn/jenkins/workspace/JenkinsTest/build/coverage
    [mkdir] Created dir: /opt/ubersvn/jenkins/workspace/JenkinsTest/build/logs
    [mkdir] Created dir: /opt/ubersvn/jenkins/workspace/JenkinsTest/build/pdepend
    [mkdir] Created dir: /opt/ubersvn/jenkins/workspace/JenkinsTest/build/phpdox

lint:
    [apply] No syntax errors detected in /opt/ubersvn/jenkins/workspace/JenkinsTest/src/index.php
    [apply] No syntax errors detected in /opt/ubersvn/jenkins/workspace/JenkinsTest/tests/bootstrap.php

phploc:
     [exec] phploc 1.7.4 by Sebastian Bergmann.
     [exec] 
     [exec] Lines of Code (LOC):                                  2
     [exec]   Cyclomatic Complexity / Lines of Code:           0.00
     [exec] Comment Lines of Code (CLOC):                         0
     [exec] Non-Comment Lines of Code (NCLOC):                    2
     [exec] 
     [exec] Namespaces:                                           0
     [exec] Interfaces:                                           0
     [exec] Traits:                                               0
     [exec] Classes:                                              0
     [exec]   Abstract:                                           0 (0.00%)
     [exec]   Concrete:                                           0 (0.00%)
     [exec]   Average Class Length (NCLOC):                       0
     [exec] Methods:                                              0
     [exec]   Scope:
     [exec]     Non-Static:                                       0 (0.00%)
     [exec]     Static:                                           0 (0.00%)
     [exec]   Visibility:
     [exec]     Public:                                           0 (0.00%)
     [exec]     Non-Public:                                       0 (0.00%)
     [exec]   Average Method Length (NCLOC):                      0
     [exec]   Cyclomatic Complexity / Number of Methods:       0.00
     [exec] 
     [exec] Anonymous Functions:                                  0
     [exec] Functions:                                            0
     [exec] 
     [exec] Constants:                                            0
     [exec]   Global constants:                                   0
     [exec]   Class constants:                                    0

pdepend:
     [exec] PHP_Depend 1.1.0 by Manuel Pichler
     [exec] 
     [exec] Parsing source files:
     [exec] .                                                                1
     [exec] 
     [exec] Executing Coupling-Analyzer:
     [exec] .     0
     [exec] 
     [exec] Executing CyclomaticComplexity-Analyzer:
     [exec] .     0
     [exec] 
     [exec] Executing Dependency-Analyzer:
     [exec] .     0
     [exec] 
     [exec] Executing Inheritance-Analyzer:
     [exec] .     0
     [exec] 
     [exec] Executing NodeCount-Analyzer:
     [exec] .     0
     [exec] 
     [exec] Executing NodeLoc-Analyzer:
     [exec] .     0
     [exec] 
     [exec] Generating pdepend log files, this may take a moment.
     [exec] 
     [exec] Time: 00:00; Memory: 7.75Mb

phpmd-ci:

phpcs-ci:

phpcpd:
     [exec] phpcpd 1.4.0 by Sebastian Bergmann.
     [exec] 
     [exec] 0.00% duplicated lines out of 2 total lines of code.
     [exec] 
     [exec] Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 2.25Mb

phpdox:
     [exec] phpdox 0.4.0 - Copyright (C) 2010 - 2012 by Arne Blankerts
     [exec] 
     [exec] 
     [exec] An error occured while trying to load the configuration file:
     [exec]     None of the candidate files found
     [exec] 
     [exec] Using --skel might get you started.
     [exec] 
     [exec] Result: 3

phpunit:
     [exec] hiPHPUnit 3.7.18 by Sebastian Bergmann.
     [exec] 
     [exec] Configuration read from /opt/ubersvn/jenkins/workspace/JenkinsTest/phpunit.xml.dist
     [exec] 
     [exec] 
     [exec] 
     [exec] Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 3.75Mb
     [exec] 
     [exec] No tests executed!
     [exec] 
     [exec] Generating code coverage report in Clover XML format ... done
     [exec] 
     [exec] Generating code coverage report in HTML format ... done

phpcb:

build:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second
[CHECKSTYLE] Collecting checkstyle analysis files...
[CHECKSTYLE] Finding all files that match the pattern build/logs/checkstyle.xml
[CHECKSTYLE] Parsing 1 files in /opt/ubersvn/jenkins/workspace/JenkinsTest
[CHECKSTYLE] Successfully parsed file /opt/ubersvn/jenkins/workspace/JenkinsTest/build/logs/checkstyle.xml of module  with 0 warnings.
[PMD] Collecting PMD analysis files...
[PMD] Finding all files that match the pattern build/logs/pmd.xml
[PMD] Parsing 1 files in /opt/ubersvn/jenkins/workspace/JenkinsTest
[PMD] Successfully parsed file /opt/ubersvn/jenkins/workspace/JenkinsTest/build/logs/pmd.xml of module  with 0 warnings.
[DRY] Collecting duplicate code analysis files...
[DRY] Finding all files that match the pattern build/logs/pmd-cpd.xml
[DRY] Parsing 1 files in /opt/ubersvn/jenkins/workspace/JenkinsTest
[DRY] Successfully parsed file /opt/ubersvn/jenkins/workspace/JenkinsTest/build/logs/pmd-cpd.xml of module  with 0 warnings.
Recording plot data
Publishing Clover coverage report...
Publishing Clover HTML report...
Publishing Clover XML report...
Publishing Clover coverage results...
[htmlpublisher] Archiving HTML reports...
[htmlpublisher] Archiving at BUILD level /opt/ubersvn/jenkins/workspace/JenkinsTest/build/API_Documentation to /opt/ubersvn/jenkins/jobs/JenkinsTest/builds/2013-03-12_14-11-41/htmlreports/API_Documentation
ERROR: Directory '/opt/ubersvn/jenkins/workspace/JenkinsTest/build/API_Documentation' exists but failed copying to '/opt/ubersvn/jenkins/jobs/JenkinsTest/builds/2013-03-12_14-11-41/htmlreports/API_Documentation'.
ERROR: This is especially strange since your build otherwise succeeded.
Build step 'Publish HTML reports' changed build result to FAILURE
[xUnit] [INFO] - Starting to record.
[xUnit] [INFO] - Processing PHPUnit-3.x (default)
[xUnit] [INFO] - [PHPUnit-3.x (default)] - 1 test report file(s) were found with the pattern 'build/logs/junit.xml' relative to '/opt/ubersvn/jenkins/workspace/JenkinsTest' for the testing framework 'PHPUnit-3.x (default)'.
[xUnit] [WARNING] - All test reports are empty.
[xUnit] [INFO] - Check 'Failed Tests' threshold.
[xUnit] [INFO] - Check 'Skipped Tests' threshold.
[xUnit] [INFO] - Setting the build status to FAILURE
[xUnit] [INFO] - Stopping recording.
[JDepend] JDepend plugin is ready
[JDepend] Found 0 classes in 0 packages
Finished: FAILURE
```

Don't know if it is helpful for you

Did it!!!

Just define phpdox.xml in project-root

```
<phpdox xmlns="http://phpdox.de/config">
    <project name="name-of-project" source="src" workdir="build/phpdox">
        <collector publiconly="false">
            <include mask="*.php" />
            <exclude mask="*Autoload.php" />
        </collector>

        <generator output="build">
            <build engine="html" enabled="true" output="api"/>
        </generator>
    </project>
</phpdox>
```

Sorry for wasting your time :/ jenkins-php.org has to be updated to make it more easyer to new Jenkins-Users ^^

Comment: Is the directory `builds/2013-03-12_12-56-15/htmlreports/API_Documentation` read- and writable for the user Jenkins runs as?

Comment: I love errors that describe themselves as "especially strange".

Comment: Because of Jenkins created the builds-Folder, I think it should be read- and writeable through himself!?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just if somebody hasn't read my EDIT:

Did it!!!

Just define phpdox.xml in project-root

```
<phpdox xmlns="http://phpdox.de/config">
    <project name="name-of-project" source="src" workdir="build/phpdox">
        <collector publiconly="false">
            <include mask="*.php" />
            <exclude mask="*Autoload.php" />
        </collector>

        <generator output="build">
            <build engine="html" enabled="true" output="api"/>
        </generator>
    </project>
</phpdox>
```

Sorry for wasting your time :/ jenkins

Comment: hey, can you tell me exactly where you put this file? I am having the exact same issue and have tried dropping this file in a number of locations - all to no avail...

Comment: in the same Folder as your build.XML file :)

Comment: `http://phpdox.de/config` doesn't exist anymore. Please use `http://xml.phpdox.net/config'`.

Answer (score 1):

Enough DiskSpace?
Maybe this helps: http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-7242
Micha

Comment: Hey Micha, this vServer is totally new, just uberSVN, Jenkins, some php-tools and 33MB SVN-Repositorys are on this Server. That shouldn't be 80GB in total!? So I don't think its the disk-space... did you have further ideas?

Comment: Not at the moment. You check the Link?

Comment: Yes I did. But that doesn't help me really.. I checked, if I did the same mistake, but not really.

Comment: For better analysis I modifyed my Question with an whole Build-Log.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling xsl on /etc/php/php.ini fixed this for me

```
extension=xsl.so
```

Also, just got this:

```
[exec] The configuratin file '/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/DEV-truvis.co/workspace/phpdox.xml' uses a wrong or outdated xml namespace.
[exec] Please ensure it uses 'http://xml.phpdox.net/config'
```

Answer (score 0):

For me (I was following jenkins-php.org), I simply had to specify the path to the `phpdox.xml` which was in my `build/` directory (along with all my other `.xml` files (`phpcs.xml` & `phpmd.xml`).

```
<!-- build.xml - phpdox section -->
<target name="phpdox" description="Generate API documentation using phpDox">
    <exec executable="phpdox">
        <!-- Specify the path to phpdox.xml -->
        <arg value="--file=${basedir}/build/phpdox.xml" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

An example `phpdox.xml` file looks like this:

https://github.com/theseer/phpdox/blob/master/phpdox.xml.dist

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still having this error, I found that within phpdox.xml, you now need to use the xmlns of "http://phpdox.net/config", thats with a .NET not .DE.

Comment: <pre> <code>[exec] The configuratin file '/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/DEV-truvis.co/workspace/phpdox.xml' uses a wrong or outdated xml namespace.
     [exec] Please ensure it uses 'http://xml.phpdox.net/config'</code></pre>