# jenkins html publisher: directory exists but failed copying to

Tags: jenkins

I've tried the answer on [Jenkins-Job fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15360733/jenkins-job-fails) but it didn't helped me.

Has anyone any different answer? Jenkins is installed on Ubuntu 12.04 under tomcat. I have configured it to make a build with CVS repository. When i am trying to make a new build it fails due to the below error.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1:34.392s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Aug 19 12:32:14 IST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/206M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[htmlpublisher] Archiving HTML reports...
[htmlpublisher] Archiving at BUILD level /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/jenkins/jobs/Data_Ingestion_Tool/workspace/DataIngestionTool/target/site/jacoco to /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/jenkins/jobs/Data_Ingestion_Tool/builds/2013-08-19_12-28-39/htmlreports/Jacoco_Coverage_Report
ERROR: Directory '/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/jenkins/jobs/Data_Ingestion_Tool/workspace/DataIngestionTool/target/site/jacoco' exists but failed copying to '/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/jenkins/jobs/Data_Ingestion_Tool/builds/2013-08-19_12-28-39/htmlreports/Jacoco_Coverage_Report'.
ERROR: This is especially strange since your build otherwise succeeded.
Build step 'Publish HTML reports' changed build result to FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE
```

Am i missing any user permissions?

I've tried giving full read-write access to

> /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/jenkins/jobs/Data_Ingestion_Tool/builds/

folder but it still doesn't help :(

i don't know how to give permissions to a logged in jenkins user. Can anybody help me in resolving this issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you find any solution for this issue...??

Comment: @neo jakson,See my answer it can help you:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/54203222/5770004

Answer (score 7):

If you ruled out disk space and permissions, then the problem is probably configuration.

The error comes because [the HTML publisher plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/htmlpublisher-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/htmlpublisher/HtmlPublisher.java#L212) copied 0 files. It could just be that your input configuration was incorrect.

Can you check your worskpace (/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/jenkins/jobs/Data_Ingestion_Tool/workspace/DataIngestionTool/target/site/jacoco) and check that the files you want to copy are under that path ?

If not, what do you have under /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/jenkins/jobs/Data_Ingestion_Tool/builds/2013-08-19_12-28-39/ ?

Comment: There are no files under (/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/jenkins/jobs/Data_Ingestion_Tool/workspace/DataIngestionTool/target/site/jacoco) and under /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/jenkins/jobs/Data_Ingestion_Tool/builds/2013-08-19_12-28-39/ , there are 3 files i,e. build.xml, changelog.xml and log file.

Comment: @neojakson if you have no files under ..../target/site/jacoco, there is your problem. E.g. you haven't run the proper maven goal for these files to appear, you are pointing to wrong location, etc.

Comment: so what is the solution?

Comment: @Mahder, this "failed copying" error, indicates that **your last build step failed** to create the file that HTML Reporter is trying to publish.

Answer (score 2):

In my case misconfiguration of HTML publisher caused the problem

```
publishHTML([
  allowMissing: false,
  alwaysLinkToLastBuild: false,
  includes: '**/*.png',     <---------------------- this line
  keepAll: true,
  reportDir: 'reports/',
  reportFiles: 'broker_portal_uat_index.html',
  reportName: 'HTML Report',
  reportTitles: 'FH BP'
 ])
```

Once I changed it `includes` to `includes: '**/*'` the problem was gone

Answer (score 1):

Got the same issue as long as my target folder was empty. Once populated with a file, at least this error stopped showing.

Comment: Faced the same issue & cause ️ this error message is quite misleading.
Found this related discussion on Jenkins bug tracker: https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-7242