# Jenkins could not generate HTML Report folder on slave-machine

Tags: jenkins, jasmine, protractor, easyhtmlreport

I am trying to generate HTML reports(Protractor Test) through Jenkins but it says 
"ERROR: Specified HTML directory 'x/y/z/Reports' does not exist". but when i run on the slave reports were generated. 
What do i need to do on the Jenkins Configuration, please help on this.
*Path is correct but it could not generate "Reports" folder on the slave.
I am using- "protractor-html-screenshot-reporter"

Comment: Looks like a typo from here. x/y/z/"Reports" and "Report" are different things.

Comment: my bad, it is "Reports" only.

Comment: Came to know that reports are writing to home directory of jenkins, how to access them. Your help is greatly appreciated. @Mayur Nagekar do you have any idea on this?

Comment: home directory of jenkins should be /var/lib/jenkins. Can you echo $WORKSPACE in the shell section of job configuration.?

Answer (score 0):

You need specify the path like "\x\y\z\Reports\", and make sure those folders is existing on your slave-machine

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

1. Click on **Workspace** Button and navigate until the HTML report folder appears.
2. Copy the full path (Even though it looks like it's before the project):

[image]

3. Paste the full path as is in the Publish HTML report plugin:

[image]

**Remember!** Location path / configuration on Bash script field (even running: cd /././. etc.) Does not affect the rest of the configuration settings on the Jenkins page.

This is why a full path is needed.