# Jenkins - HTML Publisher Plugin build fails with report directory doesnot exist

Tags: jenkins

I am using the HTML publisher plugin and I am generating html report and placing in a report folder `report/profile.html`. I have specified the path where my report is in HTML directory to archive. I gave the path as `/apps/cmjenkins/workspace/service_testapps_copy/LISA Project/Mezzo_Automation/Reports`. That gave `directory does not exist` error so gave the complete path as well: `C:/Users/dtiker/Documents/Feb24/universe1_0_testapps/service_testapps/LISA Project/Mezzo_Automation/Reports`

Below is the error i see in console output after i run my jenkins build

```
12:45:34 [htmlpublisher] Archiving HTML reports...
12:45:34 [htmlpublisher] Archiving at PROJECT level C:/Users/dtiker/Documents/Feb24/universe1_0_testapps/service_testapps/LISA Project/Mezzo_Automation/Reports to /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/API_PROFILE_HTML_Report_POC/htmlreports/HTML_Report
12:45:34 ERROR: Specified HTML directory 'C:/Users/dtiker/Documents/Feb24/universe1_0_testapps/service_testapps/LISA Project/Mezzo_Automation/Reports' does not exist.
12:45:34 Build step 'Publish HTML reports' changed build result to FAILURE
12:45:34 Finished: FAILURE
```

I verified that that directory does exist. Can someone let me know what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you try a relative path to the files?

Comment: relative path did not work. Thats why gave absolute path

Comment: You're likely not going to have the same workspace directory for every build.

Comment: so any idea how i can fix this?. what should i give in my directory path?

Comment: @user2864458 See my answer, it can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54203222/5770004

Answer (score 1):

Your job (each `node{}`) will use an own workspace, you should always reference files of the current build with a relative path!

```
publishHTML(reportDir: 'reports', reportFiles: 'profile.html'])
```

Comment: I know this is a late comment, but I am stuck on this problem. Can you expand on this some? I am having the same issue.

Comment: You need to make sure that you call the publish step in the same `node`/`agent`.

Comment: Yeah I figured it out. My mocha reports were not being put in the same place that the HTML publisher was looking. Green horn mistake.

Comment: I'm also stuck with this, I'm able to see even json files in that dir, and it's using workspace of that node (using docker-agents in here), but files are root:bin permission. Even tried to chown all files and folders and still got the error that folder is not found. Using relative paths in here.

Answer (score 1):

In my case misconfiguration of HTML publisher caused the problem

```
publishHTML([
  allowMissing: false,
  alwaysLinkToLastBuild: false,
  includes: '**/*.png',     <--------------------- this line
  keepAll: true,
  reportDir: 'reports/',
  reportFiles: 'friday_health_broker_portal_uat_index.html',
  reportName: 'HTML Report',
  reportTitles: 'FH BP'
 ])
```

Once I changed it `includes` to `includes: '**/*'` the problem was gone

Answer (score 0):

when I used file path in "filepath " instead of 'filepath ', then its working fine for me

```
stage ('publish results') {
      publishHTML([
          allowMissing: false, 
          alwaysLinkToLastBuild: true, 
          keepAll: false, 
          reportDir: "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/project/target/site/serenity", 
          reportFiles: "index.html", 
          reportName: 'HTML Report', 
          reportTitles: ''
          ])
}
```

Comment: it was helpful ! merci :)