# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library (xsl.so / libexslt.so.0)

Tags: php, xml, centos

I'm getting an error whenever I start up PHP:

**PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/xsl.so' - libexslt.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0**

I started to receive this error when I installed php-xml (running under centos).

This error occurs on both PHP version 5.3 & 5.4

Can anyone shed any light on this? php-xml still seems fully functional (DOMDocument functioning correctly).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

check in /etc/php.d/ to see if you already have xsl.ini.

I mistakenly believed I needed to insert extension=xsl.so into my /etc/php.ini file for an [issue with Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15360733/jenkins-job-fails) but its already being loaded from here. Hope this helps, it fixed my issue.