# Jenkins PHP Job Failing

Tags: php, jenkins, continuous-integration

I've setup Jenkins for my PHP app as per the instructions on jenkins-php.org.
I had a few issues with installing the various PEAR modules but I "think" they are all sorted now.
I have my source in SVN and Jenkins is pulling it in ok.

I'm using the php-template job and have customised it as per instructions.

When I run the job I get the following error...

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 5 seconds
[CHECKSTYLE] Collecting checkstyle analysis files...
[CHECKSTYLE] Finding all files that match the pattern build/logs/checkstyle.xml
[PMD] Collecting PMD analysis files...
[PMD] Finding all files that match the pattern build/logs/pmd.xml
[DRY] Collecting duplicate code analysis files...
[DRY] Finding all files that match the pattern build/logs/pmd-cpd.xml
Recording plot data
Publishing Clover coverage report...
Clover xml file does not exist in: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/CasperCheck/workspace called: build/logs/clover.xml and will not be copied to: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/CasperCheck/builds/2013-10-26_12-51-32/cloverphp/clover.xml
Could not find 'build/coverage/build/logs/clover.xml'.  Did you generate the XML report for Clover?
[htmlpublisher] Archiving HTML reports...
[htmlpublisher] Archiving at BUILD level /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/CasperCheck/workspace/build/api to /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/CasperCheck/builds/2013-10-26_12-51-32/htmlreports/API_Documentation
ERROR: Specified HTML directory '/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/CasperCheck/workspace/build/api' does not exist.
Build step 'Publish HTML reports' changed build result to FAILURE
[xUnit] [INFO] - Starting to record.
[xUnit] [INFO] - Processing PHPUnit-3.x (default)
[xUnit] [INFO] - [PHPUnit-3.x (default)] - No test report file(s) were found with the pattern 'build/logs/junit.xml' relative to '/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/CasperCheck/workspace' for the testing framework 'PHPUnit-3.x (default)'.  Did you enter a pattern relative to the correct directory?  Did you generate the result report(s) for 'PHPUnit-3.x (default)'?
[xUnit] [ERROR] - No test reports found for the metric 'PHPUnit' with the resolved pattern 'build/logs/junit.xml'. Configuration error?.
[xUnit] [INFO] - Fail BUILD because 'set build failed if errors' option is activated.
[xUnit] [INFO] - There are errors when processing test results.
[xUnit] [INFO] - Skipping tests recording.
[xUnit] [INFO] - Stop build.
[JDepend] JDepend plugin is ready
[JDepend] Couldn't generate JDepend file at 'build/logs/jdepend.xml'java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/CasperCheck/workspace/build/logs/jdepend.xml (No such file or directory)
Finished: FAILURE
```

I'm not entirely sure whats going on here. Is it possibly a permissions issue?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the issue. This ticket helped...

[Jenkins-Job fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15360733/jenkins-job-fails)

Plus, I had some further issues with the placement of some other build/config files for some for the plugins which could have been avoided if I had read the instructions on the php jenkins template site fully!

Answer (score 0):

This smells like a relative-path to the workspace issue. Does /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/CasperCheck/workspace/build/ exist?