# Jenkins PHP job failed

Tags: php, ant, jenkins, phpunit, xunit

A few days wrestling with Jenkins and errors which gave me. For now I have things stabilized somewhat, but I can not understand, because the build fails. That's what I earn and I can not figure out where I'm wrong.

Consider the following two topics:
[Jenkins PHP Job Failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19606407/jenkins-php-job-failing) , 
[Jenkins-Job fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15360733/jenkins-job-fails)

but I can not find solution to my problem.

```
[workspace] $ ant

Buildfile: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/MTR-CMS/workspace/build.xml

clean:
   [delete] Deleting directory /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/MTR-CMS/workspace/build/coverage
   [delete] Deleting directory /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/MTR-CMS/workspace/build/logs

prepare:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/MTR-CMS/workspace/build/coverage
    [mkdir] Created dir: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/MTR-CMS/workspace/build/logs

phpunit:
     [exec] PHPUnit 4.4.0 by Sebastian Bergmann.
     [exec] 
     [exec] Configuration read from /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/MTR-CMS/workspace/phpunit.xml
     [exec] 
     [exec] .
     [exec] 
     [exec] Time: 154 ms, Memory: 10.00Mb
     [exec] 
     [exec] OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
     [exec] 
     [exec] Generating code coverage report in Clover XML format ... done
     [exec] 
     [exec] Generating code coverage report in HTML format ... done

build:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second
Publishing Clover coverage report...
Publishing Clover HTML report...
Publishing Clover XML report...
Publishing Clover coverage results...
[CRAP4J] Collecting Crap4J analysis files...
[CRAP4J] Searching for report files within build/logs/crap4j.xml
[CRAP4J] Using the new FileSetBuilder
[CRAP4J] No crap4j report files were found. Configuration error?
Build step 'Report Crap' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'Report Crap' marked build as failure
[xUnit] [INFO] - Starting to record.
[xUnit] [INFO] - Processing PHPUnit-3.x (default)
[xUnit] [INFO] - [PHPUnit-3.x (default)] - No test report file(s) were found with the pattern 'build/logs/junit.xml' relative to '/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/MTR-CMS/workspace' for the testing framework 'PHPUnit-3.x (default)'.  Did you enter a pattern relative to the correct directory?  Did you generate the result report(s) for 'PHPUnit-3.x (default)'?
[xUnit] [ERROR] - No test reports found for the metric 'PHPUnit' with the resolved pattern 'build/logs/junit.xml'. Configuration error?.
[xUnit] [INFO] - Failing BUILD.
[xUnit] [INFO] - There are errors when processing test results.
[xUnit] [INFO] - Skipping tests recording.
[xUnit] [INFO] - Stop build.
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Please share your build.xml or phpunit.xml file

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What's not clear?

```
[CRAP4J] Collecting Crap4J analysis files...
[CRAP4J] Searching for report files within build/logs/crap4j.xml
[CRAP4J] Using the new FileSetBuilder
[CRAP4J] No crap4j report files were found. Configuration error?
Build step 'Report Crap' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'Report Crap' marked build as failure`
```

Your [**Crap4J plugin**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Crap4J+Plugin) is setting the build result to failed.

It also says that it cannot find report files, so your build is not producing the `.xml`'s that the plugin needs, or you didn't specify the location of those files

Answer (score 2):

Please check your build file

your build config file can not create 'junit.xml' file

or

check phpunit.xml file

```
<logging>
    <log type="coverage-html" target="coverage"/>
    <log type="coverage-clover" target="clover/clover.xml"/>
    <log type="coverage-crap4j" target="logs/crap4j.xml"/>
    <log type="junit" target="logs/junit.xml" logIncompleteSkipped="false"/>
</logging>
```